# Temporary data in Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need a solution for storing userIds and deleting the data every 24 hours in a Firebase function.

What's the best practice for this case?

Comment: Have a look at the doc page about [Manage data retention with TTL policies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/ttl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Firebase has a special system for this

Example:

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every 5 minutes!');
  return null;
});
```

More info is available at:

https://firebase.blog/posts/2019/04/schedule-cloud-functions-firebase-cron

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions